# MS Excel Partial Compare and Copy values from one cell to another

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

How can i partial compare records in two cell using `Excel-formula`

Let Say i have `AA BB` in `Sheet1- A1` and  `Test` in Sheet1 B1 and `AA VV` in `sheet2 cell A1` How can i partial Compare the two cell using the first word or word before space and create something shown on below #3

## 1. Sheet1 look like below

```
   A2          B2
 -----        -----
 AA BB        test.
```

## 2. Sheet 2 looks like

```
   A2         
 -----        
 AA VV
```

## 3. I want to see Sheet 3 as

```
   A2          B2
 -----        -----
 AA VV        test.
```

Compare the first word if match

Comment: Do you manually input the value on A2 of Sheet 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming Sheet 1 has a range of values like the one below, and column A of Sheet 3 is equated to column A of Sheet 2:

```
     A        B
--------------------
1  AA BB  test.
2  CC DD  test..
3  EE FF  test...
4  GG HH  test....
5  II JJ  test.....
```

You can use this formula on column B of Sheet 3:

```
=VLOOKUP("*" & MID($A1, 1, FIND(" ", $A1)-1) & "*", Sheet1!$A$1:$B$5, 2, FALSE)
```